# Is it really required to use 'next-redux-wrapper' in a 'Next.js + Redux Toolkit' application when doing only 'static generation'?

Tags: redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper

I'm planning to create a **Next.js** application along with **Redux Toolkit** for state management.
I'll only be doing **Static Generation** (using **getStaticProps** & **getStaticPaths**).

Do I need to use **next-redux-wrapper** (https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) ?

Can I get all the benefits of static generation without using **next-redux-wrapper**?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is — it's not required, but it makes things more convenient. Even for static.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if you need only static generation, adding Redux will make your life much harder. Since **getStaticProps** (as well as **getServerSideProps**) is done on the server, every page navigation will result in the new redux store, that would be quite painful to properly hydrate with the already existent client side state.

Redux is only good when you initialise it once with the classical **getInitialProp** and then only work with in on the client side.

If you still have a lot of client side state management in **useEffect**, having Redux could make sense, but read carefully the hydration part of the **next-redux-wrapper** doc.